# apache url rewrite - change parameter name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

How can I use apache rewrite to change this:

```
http://server/info/BRUCE?eia=A25&ref=187&.x=8&.y=2
```

To this:

```
http://server/info/BRUCE?eia=A25&ref=187&x=8&y=2
```

The only difference being that:

- ".x" gets converted to "x"
- ".y" gets converted to "y"

I've tried the following but no luck:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))\.x=((?:&|$).*)
RewriteRule /path /path?%1x=%2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))\.x=([^&]*)&\.y=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(info/BRUCE/?)$ /$1?%1x=%2&y=%3 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava, that's very helpful. I don't want it to change the path, I just want to change the .x and .y. I think what you've got is very close - how do I keep the original path? thank you

Comment: You are brilliant my friend